# Automatically login and retry the original request when there is 401 error code in java

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x

I am using Apache HttpClient to consume the API calls.

We are getting sign in token using login API call and using this token as header parameter in all other API calls.
This signin token will expire after some time then subsequent API calls will return 401 unauthorized error.
I want Apache HttpCleint can detect 401 errors and automatically sign in and retry the original API call.

By googling I found the link which is exactly my requirement.
[Automatically retry on 401 and send specific request with HttpClient 4.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24032353/automatically-retry-on-401-and-send-specific-request-with-httpclient-4-3?rq=1)

I can not use OkHttpClient as suggested here, but the other solution which is suggested here is that write a Proxy class over HttpClient that captured "execute" method result.
I don't have an idea on how to do this.

Can anyone please help me on this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can have a class like `MyHttpClient` in your code that implements the `HttpClient` interface. It can use the decorator pattern, which means it will have an internal instance of the real `HttpClient` class and delegate almost all its method calls to that class.

```
public class MyHttpClient implements HttpClient {
    private HttpClient httpClient;
    private String signinToken = ""

    public MyHttpClient() {
        this.httpClient = HttpClient5Factory.createHttpClient();
        this.signinToken = SigninTokenProvider.getToken();
    }

    @Override
    public HttpParams getParams() {
        return this.httpClient.getParams();
    }

    @Override
    public ClientConnectionManager getConnectionManager() {
        return this.httpClient.getConnectionManager();
    }

    ...
}
```

You can then implement the logic to fetch the signin header in this class, or if you have it in other classes, this class can call them to refresh the signin token when needed. I think it make much more sense to add the signin header in this class so you would have the signin handling just in one place.

In the implementation of `execute` methods, you should have a code like this:

```
@Override
public HttpResponse execute(HttpUriRequest request) throws IOException, ClientProtocolException {

    //  add signin header to each request
    request.addHeader(new BasicHeader("Authorization", this.signinToken));

    HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);
    if(response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_UNAUTHORIZED) {
        //  do the authentication process again
        this.signinToken = SigninTokenProvider.getToken();
        request.removeHeader("Authorization");
        request.addHeader(new BasicHeader("Authorization", this.signinToken));

        //  resend the request
        response = httpClient.execute(request);
    }

    return response;
}
```

As you can see, you can make a call to the actual API and check the response status. If it's 401, then you can redo the authentication process and fetch a new signin value and retry the request using the new signin value.

Comment: Thank you very much for clear information. As you suggested I have created a class by implementing HttpClient interface and overridden all its methods along with execute method with custom implementation. In my custom class getParams() and getConnectionManager() methods are showing as deprecated as I am using 4.5.8 version of httpclient.Can I use any other replacement for these to replace deprecated methods ?

Comment: It's deprecated, so if someone tries to call them, should be aware that those method would not exist in near future versions. But for you that are implementing that interface, you should still override them and delegate the calls to the underlying class. Whenever you upgraded to a version that doesn't have these methods at all, then you should also remove these two methods from your implementation.

Comment: This solution is extremely helpful. Thank you.